# Repeated hardware failures

Tags: hardware-failure, ups, cmos

I got the following situation:

In less than 2 weeks, three PCs of mine failed, 2 of which are industrial-grade workstations.

All of them failed while awakening from standby (not hibernation), one windows, two linux. Blank screen at boot, no error codes emitted by the bios.

Resetting CMOSes seems to solve the problem (they boot normally), but as I put them into standby, they fail again, needing another cmos reset. I even tried to upgrade all the BIOSes, with no result (bios upgraded, but they fail nonetheless).

The PCs were connected to a rather old APC Back-UPS pro, but even imagining the UPS could have caused the problem, I'd like to know what went awry.
It is the most curious problem I encountered in two decades.

Two Fujitsu Xeon workstations, one PC that I built myself (quality components).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try replacing the onboard battery.

Comment: Is resetting the CMOS the only way to get them to boot after this occurs? If you just do a hard reset (cycle power or press reset button) do they boot normally? If not, I would agree with the previous commenter, replace the CMOS battery and retest.

Comment: No, a reset from the button (or even the switch on the PSU) doesn't work.

Comment: I will replace the batteries, but mates, 3 batteries in two weeks? The PCs are all of different age..

Comment: Might be unstable power lines. Surge protectors might help.

Comment: Mates, sorry for the delay, I just forgot to check the thread. Replacing the battery worked. So if you would put it into a proper answer, I'd be happy to accept it.